# Which is the value of the integral $\int_0^a d\mu(x)?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I apologize in advance for my question which is probably dumb, but I prefer to ask.

Let $\mu$ be a measure supported in $[0, 1]$, $\mu\ge 0$. If $0<a<1$, which is the value of the integral
$$\int_0^a d\mu(x)?$$

If $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, the previous integral should reduce to
$$\int_0^a dx = a,$$

but what about the case of a measure $\mu$ as described above?

Comment: Nope, the latter is actually the case not for point measure but for Lebesgue measure

Comment: In general it is just $\mu([0,a])) or one of other three cases of endpoints included or excluded.  and it may matter here whether endpoint are included or not, definitely for Dirac measure.

Comment: @SBF, thank you. So, in the most possible general case, I only should write $\mu([0, a])$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the definition of the Lebesgue(esque) integrals:
$$
\int_A \mu(dx) = \int 1_A(x)\mu(dx) = \mu(A)
$$
where $1_A$ is the indicator function of the set $A$ and the second integral is taken over the whole space that supports your measure $\mu$, in your case $\Bbb R$. Note that if $\mu=\delta_0$ then
$$
0 = \int_{(0, a]}\mu(dx) \neq \int_{[0, a]}\mu(dx) = 1
$$
so we can't simply write here $\int_0^a\mu(dx)$ without ambiguity.